# flutter disable animation router navigator.pushNamed

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, routes, router

I use a router for my app.
and use Navigator.pushNamed for use it.
but I don't want an animation for it.

```
MaterialApp(
debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
 routes: routes,
 initialRoute: '/firstPage')
```

here is my routes :

```
Map<String, WidgetBuilder> routes = <String, WidgetBuilder>{
  '/firstPage': (context) => const FirstPage(),
  '/': (context) => const BottomNavBar( activeTabIndex: 0, widgetActive: ExploreHome(), ),

   // another routes
  };
```

and I use this for call routes :

```
 Navigator.pushNamed(
    context,
    '/',
    arguments: {
    "title": "explore",
    "text": "something"
     },);
```

and use   `final args = (ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments ??{"title": " ", "text": ""}) as dynamic;` to get argument for my `ExploreHome()` class.

so how can I remove the animation router?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `onGenerateRoute` in your `MaterialApp` widget.

```
onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
  if (settings.name == "/initialRoute") {
    return PageRouteBuilder(
      transitionDuration: Duration.zero,
      settings: settings,
      pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => InitialPage(),
  }
  // default route
  return PageRouteBuilder(
         transitionDuration: Duration.zero,
         settings: settings,
         pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => DefaultRoute(),
  },
```

Comment: i've use `routes: routes,
              onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
                if (settings.name == "/firstPage") {
                  return PageRouteBuilder(
                      transitionDuration: Duration.zero,
                      settings: settings,
                      pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => FirstPage());
                }
              },` this but still have animation

Comment: I have many routes. I don't know wich one  could I write in `DefaultPage` and `InitialPage`

Comment: I have updated my answer, try again with this code

Comment: I have many routes. I don't know wich one could I write in DefaultPage and InitialPage

Comment: then add else if?

Answer (score -1):

However, its late but maybe helpful for someone

If you don’t want to use  default route animation in flutter then just use this code

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
      context,
      PageRouteBuilder(
        settings: RouteSettings(name: routeName),
        pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) {
          return  YourWidget();
        },
      ),
      (route) => false,
    );
```